# Add a DOM property in JSX

Tags: reactjs

This does not work with Custom Elements in React as of today (16.8.6):

```
<my-element myProperty="foo" />
```

As a workaround, I'm using a ref to add a DOM property to my node:

```
myElement.myProperty = "foo";

<my-element ref={myElement} />
```

...but I'm wondering if there's a shorter way, maybe something like:

```
<my-element myProperty.property = "foo" />
```

...similar to what Vue or Angular offer:

```
<my-element :myProperty.prop="foo" /> <!-- Vue -->

<my-element [attr.myProperty]="foo" /> <!-- Angular -->
```

Comment: its working for me. are you using typescript?

Comment: is <my-element a html5 tag or a component?

Comment: It's a custom element.

Comment: Examples don't match. It's myProperty.property in one place and myProperty in another.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DOM is case-insensitive, this should work the same way in React:

```
<my-element myProperty="foo" />
```

And Angular:

```
<my-element [attr.myProperty]="foo" />
```

And result in setting `myproperty` *attribute*, i.e. `domElement.getAttribute('myproperty')`, not `domElement.myProperty`.

Setting DOM element properties and not attributes like `<my-element :myProperty.prop="foo" />` is currently not supported in React.

If the intention is to set DOM element *property*, this should be done explicitly on a ref:

```
class MyElement extends Component {  
  elRef = createRef();

  componentDidMount() {    
    this.elRef.current.myProperty = this.props.myProperty;
  }

  render() {
    const {myProperty, ...props} = this.props;
    return <my-element {...props} ref={this.elRef} />;
  }
}
```

Comment: Why should this be done explicitly on a ref? It is noisy and error prone.

Comment: Because you cannot do this otherwise. You mentioned Angular and Vue as examples, but it's the same there. `myProperty="foo"` is an attribute. When you pass an attribute, this sets an attribute, not a property. If it's noisy and error-prone, you can do this once in custom component.

Comment: I'm pretty certain that in Vue, using `:myProperty.prop="foo"` sets the property, not the attribute. That's why they built it in the first place. I don't understand why React shouldn't/couldn't have something similar. "Because you cannot do this otherwise" is a temporary thing I hope.

Comment: I'm not familiar with `:myProperty.prop` Vue syntax. Are you sure it's allowed? AFAIK v-bind (`:`) is supposed to just set an attribute on DOM elements. As for Angular, I'm certain it works the same way and sets `myproperty` attribute, not `myProperty`. I'm not sure if this will be ever changed in React because this seems to be an edge case. Usually if we need to change the way DOM element works (either custom or built-in), we create wrapper component. Added it for completeness.

Comment: I see, good to know. There's no such thing for Angular too, so this is Vue vs React. You can open an issue for React but I doubt it will be fulfilled because they try to keep it simple.

Comment: Agreed - and yes they'll probably not gonna implement it:
https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/15557

Comment: Btw. I could pick your answer if you add something like "this is not possible right now".

Comment: Sure, added a clarification.